# League of Legends character model width

Tags: league-of-legends

Is the area the registers as a hit on an enemy character when casting a skill-shot the same for all characters? Or does it differ from character to character?

Comment: Ever seen a 6 feast stack cho gath ;) , other than him and Nasus/Renek while using their ultimate all other characters should have very very similar hitboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the same, it differs.

[*proof*](http://www.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?s=95f2387468933c969a77d8b692e5e286&p=5668875#post5668875)

Comment: That's a single exception to what I think is an otherwise perfectly equivalent rule.